# Keras hanging during training when paired with celery

Tags: django, tensorflow, keras, celery

I have code that trains a neural network using Keras.

First, I run it through a grid search-like algorithm to get the best parameters and then I use the best parameters to do the real predictions.

The code works completely fine on its own; it's only after I run it with celery (Django backend) that I start to have the problem stated in the title.

To clarify, training works completely fine during the grid search, but when it's done and runs again on the best parameters, it just hangs on 'Epoch 1/1'.

Upon research, I read that I need to keep the keras imports to one area, as it doesn't work with multiprocessing. However, I made sure that was the case and even tried putting the keras imports inside the function that trains it, and still having the same problem.

EDIT: I tried the following and still having the same problem...

```
@worker_process_init.connect()
def init_worker_process(**kwargs):

    import tensorflow as tf
    session_conf = tf.ConfigProto(
       intra_op_parallelism_threads=1,
       inter_op_parallelism_threads=1
    )

    import keras
    from keras import backend as K
    K.clear_session()
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    tf.set_random_seed(7)
    sess = tf.Session(graph=tf.get_default_graph(), config=session_conf)
    K.set_session(sess)

    from keras.models import Sequential
    from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, LSTM, GRU
    from keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping
    from keras.optimizers import Adam, Nadam, Adamax, RMSprop
    from keras import regularizers
    from keras.initializers import glorot_uniform, Orthogonal

@shared_task
def myfunc(inputs...):
    #...call function that performs everything, including training with keras
```

My question is: how do I get Keras to work properly with celery?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow/Keras with django not working correctly with celery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45017573/tensorflow-keras-with-django-not-working-correctly-with-celery)

Comment: edited my post to show that the solution there doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

```
GRAPH = tf.get_default_graph()

@shared_task
def myfunc(inputs...):
    with GRAPH.as_default():
       model_loaded = model.create_model() // define archs, load weight etc
       model_loaded.fit(data,labels ....)
```

tensorflow is thread-specific data structure so you can't use tf.load_model, tf.fit etc in celery which is process driven arch.

for that you need to use [eventlet](https://pypi.org/project/eventlet/) or [gevent](https://pypi.org/project/gevent/) library .

> pip install gevent

run celery as :

> celery -A mysite worker **--pool gevent** -l info

Comment: Celery 4.4.0 (released few days ago) adds support for the regular thread pool with the `--pool thread` mode.